# Communicating between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to have two directives talking to each other. I am trying to follow http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/. Here is my code:

```
Directives = angular.module("app.directives", []);
Directives.directive('basket', function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.content = [];
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
    }
};
```

});

```
Directives.directive('appple', function ($compile) {
return {
    require: "basket",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel, basketCtrl) {
```

......

My error is:
Error: $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller
Controller 'basket', required by directive 'apple', can't be found!

Any idea?

Thanks

Here is my markup

```
<basket apple></basket>
<div easyui-layout fit="true" style="height:100%;">
<div data-options="region:'west',title:'Asset Tree',split:true" style="width:30%;">
    <table assets-treegrid ng-model="assets" fit="true" loadMsg=""
           singleselect="true" idField="id" treeField="name"></table>
</div>
<div region="center">
    <div easyui-layout fit="true">
        <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" style="height:40%;">
            <table id="tg" alarms-treegrid ng-model="alarms" pagination="false" fit="true"
                   rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" idField="id"></table>
        </div>
        <div data-options="region:'center'">      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Directives.directive('alarmsTreegrid', function ($compile) {
return {
    //restrict: 'AE',
    require: "basket",
    //require: "easyuiWindow",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel, basketCtrl) {
```

Comment: Please post your markup.  This happens when you declare an apple without a basket.

Comment: fiddle link posted is an empty fiddle,. If you post data to fiddle need to save it. Please show relevant code within the question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks!

Comment: But it's not working with real code that I am going to modify.

Comment: Adding working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/py7gxw58/. If you uncomment  //require: "basket" in easyuiLayout directive you will see that is not working. Please help.

Comment: Somebody, please help. I am totally stuck.

Comment: Are you still having the problem?  The fiddle doesn't produce the error as far as I can tell

Comment: Ok, that reproduces the error.  It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  It doesn't seem like your easyui-layout directive should require a basket, particularly since there are two easyui-layout elements in your markup.  Another thing is that you restrict basket to 'E' or element only, so you would need to apply the easyui-layout to that element.  Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/py7gxw58/ which is probably closer to what you want.  Notice I changed the basket restrict to AE and applied basket attributes to both of the easyui-layout elements

Comment: Well, but now it's not running with require commented out. I only use basket for testing purposes.

Comment: I have simplified it into the following: http://jsfiddle.net/py7gxw58/1/ still does not work